# SQL ERROR When i join 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

Sorry let me revise. I have a three tables:

events_year
• EventID
• YearID
• id

Date
• YearID
• Year

Event
• EventID
• EventName
• EventType

i want to dispay a record from the three tables like so:

EventName - Year:   Marathon - 2008

i linked it to a table called "members" which contains a ID number field (members-id)

so i can limit the results to members id = $un(which is a username from a session)

I need to join the three tables and limit the results to the specific ID number record

Here is my portion of the code:

```
$query =    "SELECT * FROM members JOIN events_year ON members.id = events_year.id ";
            "SELECT * FROM Event JOIN events_year ON Event.EventID = events_year.EventID WHERE username = '$un'";
            "SELECT * FROM Date JOIN events_year ON Date.YearID = events_year.YearID WHERE username = '$un'";


$results = mysql_query($query)
    or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo $row['Year'];
    echo " - ";
    echo $row['Event'];
    echo "<br>";
    }
```

Comment: What are the table definitions?

Comment: What did you do to debug this yourself? Did you try printing/logging the contents of `$row`?

Comment: You can't run three select queries like that

Comment: Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: Why do you title that with "SQL error"? There is no SQL error.

Comment: It's best to define which columns you are selecting rather than using the wild card. That way you'll get what you expect rather than errors for missing columns.

Comment: I have three Tables: The event_year table have id fields to event and Date. I need to join the three

Comment: If i define the colomns i get: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @SebastianOpperman please give us the definitions of your tables :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the notices are almost self-explaining. There are no `'Year'` and `'EventName'` fields in the resultset. It's difficult (or: impossible) to tell why this happens as you haven't given your table-structure, but i guess this: `'Year'` is a field of the `date`-table, `'EventName'` is a field of the `event`-table - you're only selecting from `members` so this fields don't occur.

I don't understand why there are three sql-statements but only one is assigned to a variable - the other two are just standing there and do nothing. Please explain this and put more information into your question about what you're trying to achive, what your table-structure looks like and whats your expected result.

I think what you really wanted to do is some kind of joined query, so please take a look at [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) to see how this works.

finally, i think your query should look like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  members
INNER JOIN
  events_year ON members.id = events_year.id
INNER JOIN
  Event ON Event.EventID = events_year.EventID
INNER JOIN
  ´Date´ ON ´Date´.YearID = events_year.YearID
WHERE
  members.username = '$un'
```

Comment: I am surprised you can have a table called 'Date' I thought this was a reserved word in MySQL.

Comment: edit: oh it appears you can. TIL. Although, I wouldn't recommend this as a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Does the field 'Year' exist in the query output ?  I suspect not.

Comment: Also you say in your title you are joining tables.  You should perhaps do a little research on that because a 'join' might not be what you think it is.  The 'join' keyword in your sql statements is important.

Answer (score 0):

the string $query is only using the first line of text:

```
    "SELECT * FROM members JOIN events_year ON members.id = events_year.id ";
```

and not the others.

The query itself is not returning any fields that are called Year or EventName.

Do a var_dump($row) to find out what is being returned.